# TinyMCE - uncaught exception: module [5] returned undefined when using local javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iis, tinymce

I am updating TinyMCE from 4.6.1 to 4.9.2 in my ASP.NET MVC application. I replaced the old tinymce.min.js file with the new one. When I run the app with IIS I get a console error and my textarea's do not display. The console error is, "uncaught exception: module [5] returned undefined".

If I replace tinymce.min.js with the original(4.6.1) it works again. If I use the second script tag below to get the externally hosted javascript file it works. I made sure the static file I have downloaded is the same exact file that I get from the second script tag. I also restarted the site in IIS.

```
@* this does NOT work with version 4.9.2, using version 4.6.1 works *@
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Href("~/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js")"></script> 

@* this works (4.9.2) *@
<script src='https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js'></script>
```

My best guess is that the issue involves IIS. My IIS version is 10.0.16299.15.

EDIT: Also, I have confirmed that the javascript file is successfully fetched.

Comment: Doubtful it has anything do with IIS - you've already confirmed that the _"javascript file is **successfully** fetched"_ (which is all IIS does).

Comment: TinyMCE is far more than one file - there are a whole set of plugins and skins that also need to be available.  Did you deploy all that makes up TinyMCE to the server?

Comment: You're both right. I was missing a javascript file, theme.min.js to be exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you include everything. I only included the main javascript file. If deploying locally make sure to download the full package. The [self-hosted](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/self-hosted/) page on tiny.cloud was down when I was trying to get the files so I just grabbed the main js file.

The particular file I was missing was theme.min.js.